# C - Passing struct addresses as function arguments

Tags: c, struct

Just trying to work out here a little conceptual problem here. In this example in a textbook it's trying to pass by reference the address to a struct to the below function.

In my mind I assume that since I passed "&address", I would have to dereference this within the function to use the struct operations, like this for example

```
(*planet)->name;
```

, which is made all the more worse that they are using "&planet" in the function, wouldn't this just be like

```
&(&planet)
```

It just looks to me like they are using the struct operators *on the address of the struct*, NOT the struct itself.

```
if (read_planet_ptr(&planet) != EOF) {

...


int read_planet_ptr(planet_t *planet) {

  int nvals_read;
  printf("Enter %s:\n", PLANETPROMPT);
  nvals_read = scanf("%s %s %lf %lf %lf",
    planet->name,
    planet->orbits,
    &planet->distance,
    &planet->mass,
    &planet->radius);
  if (nvals_read != 5) {
    return EOF;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Any help is gladly appreciated

Comment: They are using `&planet->distance`, which is `&(planet->distance)`, and that is correct. `planet` is derefenced by `->` to get to `distance`, and `scanf()` needs a pointer to that member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&planet->distance` is actually evaluated as  `&(planet->distance)`, so means taking address of the member of the structure, which `scanf()` requires for updating that member with input value.

Answer (score 2):

The  `planet->name` operation is equivalent to saying `(*planet).name`, so that should resolve the confusion about name and orbits.

`&planet->distance`, and the other ones that use the dereference operator, goes into the realm of operator precedence:

The operator `->` has a higher precedence than `&`, thus the compiler will evaluate it as equivalent to: `&(planet->distance)`, instead of `(&planet)->distance`.  Though, it would have been nice if the example included parentheses in the first place, to avoid such confusion :).

Source I used for operator precedence: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1):

We can have the following cases, depending on what "planet" is -

**Case 1:** If you have declared "planet" as pointer to your structure i.e.

```
        planet_t *planet;
```

The "read_planet_ptr" should look like:

read_planet_ptr(planet_t **planet)

BECAUSE : 
when you pass the address of a pointer to any function, then you need a double pointer i.e. **
to receive that address. then you can dereference in the following manner : 
          (*planet)->info

**Case 2:** - If "planet" is an instance of the type "planet_t", then the function read_planet_ptr should work correctly.